# Is there a formula that links between emited sound level (dB) and specific heat capacity?

Tags: waves, acoustics

I'm doing an experiment on soundproofing and seeing how different materials with different specific heat capacities affect the level of sound emitted from a music speaker. Each material is formed into a box and put over the speaker, and a sound level sensor is used to detect the emitted sound. I was wondering if there is a formula that relates the two? Or is there a formula that relates S.H.C to anything else sound-related e.g. sound intensity